# How to launch Amazon RDS Multi_AZ DB Cluster Deployment (Instance with 2 standby Instances) using Terraform?

Tags: amazon-web-services, terraform, amazon-rds, terraform-provider-aws

According to AWS documentation there is a possibility to launch AWS either using Multi-AZ DB Instance deployment (1 Standby Instance) or Multi-AZ DB Cluster deployment (2 standby Instances) according to this page: https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonRDS/latest/UserGuide/Concepts.MultiAZ.html

But in Terraform AWS Provider documentation page (https://registry.terraform.io/providers/hashicorp/aws/latest/docs/resources/db_instance) I see `multi_az` argument which allows the creation of DB Instance with 1 standby Instance, but I don't know how to have 2 standby Instances. Also, there is `aws_rds_cluster` resource, but it is intended for Amazon Aurora as I understand from documentation.

What should be provided arguments into `aws_db_instance` resource to have Multi-AZ deployment with 2 standby Instances ?